# readLine for a variable number of Ints

Tags: kotlin, readline

Is there a way to code something like this in kotlin for a variable number of ints? For example the input should be "1 3 5" or "3 2 2 7" (String with space-separated Ints). And I am not allowed to use java librarys.

```
val (x, y) = readLine()!!.split(' ').map(String::toInt)
println(x+y)
```

Thanks in advance.

Comment: What does your input look like?

Comment: I edited the question, I do not need strings, I need ints :D The input should be something like "2 3 4" or "1 8 5 2". Just a variable number of random ints.

Comment: It’s really unclear what your asking. Is the input a list of Ints or a String with space-separated Ints? And what is the “this” in “something like this”?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want to just print each string, then you can use [forEach](https://kotlinlang.org/api/latest/jvm/stdlib/kotlin.collections/for-each.html#kotlin.collections$forEach(kotlin.collections.Iterable((kotlin.collections.forEach.T)),%20kotlin.Function1((kotlin.collections.forEach.T,%20kotlin.Unit)))/action)

```
readLine()!!.split(' ').forEach{ println(it) }
```

If you want to print as int, then you can use `forEach` with `toInt()`

```
readLine()!!.split(' ').forEach{ println(it.toInt()) }
```

Or if you want sum you can use [sumBy](https://kotlinlang.org/api/latest/jvm/stdlib/kotlin.collections/sum-by.html) directly

```
readLine()!!.split(' ').sumBy{ it.toInt() }
```

Answer (score 0):

Found a solution for my problem:

```
var list: List<Int> = readLine()!!.split(' ').map(String::toInt)
for(m in  list){
    println(m)
}
```